# Magento - Attribute Relationships

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working with an auto-parts company and I've come across the task of loading their fitment data. The fitment data contains many attributes but the most basic to start with is Year, Make, and Model. You may have one part (one SKU) with thousands of vehicles found in the fitment data because parts often fit many vehicles. The fitment data is meant to power the layered navigation on the left hand side of the product list.

As such, I'm trying to determine if there is a way to have attribute relationships. In other words, it'd work like the following...

SKU 001: 
Does it fit a 2012 Vehicle? Yes 
Does it fit a 2012 Hyundai? Yes 
Does it fit a 2012 Hyundai Elantra? Yes

And the system would conclude... the part fits.

SKU 002:
Does it fit a 2012 Vehicle? Yes 
Does it fit a 2012 Hyundai? Yes 
Does it fit a 2012 Hyundai Elantra? No

And the system would conclude... the part does not fit.

---

The relationships must exist because I can't just put 2012 in an attribute.. the part may fit some 2012 vehicles and not others. I'm wondering if an extension helps with this or if someone has any ideas.

Please help in any way possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of your Magento, you can add a multiple select/dropdown option attribute where you can enter your available cars (manually) and on the admin product page choose which ones are available for your part. In the view, pull this data. using

```
$_product->getvariable();
```

These can either be IDS or productname-ids so you can process the results in the view. But this method can be messy when you have thousands of products.

You can also use upsell or crosssell to choose cars that will fit the part and pull that data on the product page and have the relation that way. same can be done with crossell.

[Magento - Get upsell products list](http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento-get-upsell-products-list-using-product-id.html)

Only those attributes that are assigned to layer navigation will be used in the navigation. However you can customize the navigation view to have customized options based on your current product. I'm assuming this is the navigation you require:

```
Home
part ABC
->2013 Models
->->Honda
 ->->->CRV
->->Toyota
->->->Camry
->2012 Models 
->->Honda
->->->CRV
->->Toyota
->->->Corolla
```

[Dependant Layered Navigation filters](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/dependant-layered-navigation-filters-in-magento/)

A third option is a extension that provides similar functionality and modify it for your needs. There is this extensiont that may apply to your needs:

[Part Finder extension Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/part-finder.html)